# Oauth2 Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I try to use spring to make a login and registration system and use Oauth2

these are errors
`Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/springboot/SchoolManagementSystem_Cilent/config/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:9000"`

For my client side config:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    private static final String[] WHITE_LIST = {
            "/home",
            "/register",
            "/verifyRegistration*",
            "/resendVerifyToken*"
    };

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .antMatchers(WHITE_LIST).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login(oauth2login ->
                        oauth2login.loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/api-client-oidc"))
                .oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();

    }
}
```

client side application.yml

```
  port: 8081

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb
    username: root
    password: Cwj082711
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          api-client-oidc:
            provider: spring
            client-id: api-client
            client-secret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope: openid
            client-name: api-client-oidc
          api-client-authorization-code:
            provider: spring
            client-id: api-client
            client-secret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/authorized"
            scope: api.read
            client-name: api-client-authorization-code
        provider:
          spring:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:9000
```

my oauth authorization server config:

```
package com.springboot.Oauthauthorizationserver.config;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.AuthorizationGrantType;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClientAuthenticationMethod;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.OidcScopes;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.ClientSettings;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.ProviderSettings;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.UUID;


@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        return http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("api-client")
                .clientSecret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"))
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8081/login/oauth2/code/api-client-oidc")
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8081/authorized")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope("api.read")
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();


        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }


    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        RSAKey rsaKey = generateRsa();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }

    private static RSAKey generateRsa() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProviderSettings providerSettings() {
        return ProviderSettings.builder()
                .issuer("http://localhost:9000")
                .build();
    }
}
```

My oauth default security config:

```
import com.springboot.Oauthauthorizationserver.service.CustomAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class DefaultSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;


    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeHttpRequests ->
                        authorizeHttpRequests.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();

    }

    @Autowired
    public void bindAuthenticationProvider(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

}
```

So can anyone tell me what is the problem, I am just new to learn spring stuff and try to make a web app. Please help me!!!

Comment: Check this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-auth-server

Comment: Please provide Authorization server application.yml. Seems like this server is started on different than 9000 port

Answer (score 1):

Create an **application.yml** file and write the port:

```
server:
  port: 9000
```

> Note: If you use **Spring Authorization Server 1.0.0 (Current)** then you
> won't find ***ProviderSettings*** class.

```
@Bean
public ProviderSettings providerSettings() {
    return ProviderSettings.builder()
            .issuer("http://localhost:9000")
            .build();
}
```

Rather use:

```
@Bean
public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
    return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
            .build();
}
```

And set Issuer URI:

```
issuer-uri: http://localhost:9000
```

Hope you get resolved and enjoy coding.